# Confusion between は and が

Tags: は-and-が

The following is an exercise from [Tae Kim's Guide](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/particlesintro_ex).

I have to pick は or が to fill in the blanks:

> ジム）アリス　____　誰？
>
> ボブ）友達だ。彼女　____　アリスだ

I think we should use は after アリス in the first sentence, but I'm confused about the second sentence.  I think it should be は after 彼女, but the correct answer is apparently が.  Could someone please explain?

Comment: Though I know they want to teach は/が but 「アリスは誰？」 sounds pretty unnatural (or Japanese-as-a-foreign-language-esque).  Most native speakers would say　「アリスって誰？」.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to give an answer based on the web site you are using. If you want more detail please ask. (FYI: There is book on the difference b/w は & が but I would suggest looking at a few of the Q&A on this website first and make a note of the comment from Tokyo Nagoya for future reference.)

The website you are looking at explains (quote):

"We ..use the topic particle [は]to explain the current topic of conversation.
Sample: 誰？ （Topic: アリス） ＝ アリスは誰？"

And later:

"the 「が」 particle is only used when you want to identify something out of many other possibilities”

If we apply these to the task given:

Line 1:   "ジム）　アリス_*_*_誰？" simply requires us to to refer to the example taken from the previous section to illustrate how to the topic particle is used.  I assume this is clear but, just in case, Alice is the topic of the conversation because Jim is asking about her.

Line2: ボブ）　"友達だ。彼女____アリスだ" is the application of the explanation quoted above:

We can infer from line one that there are several candidates who could be Alice, Jim is asking Bob, which one.

As per the explanation given, が is used to identify Alice from the possibilities given.  I would guess from the information available that of the possibilities, at least one of these, but not all, is a friend.  Bob's first statement ("友達だ”) is intended to help narrow down the possibilities. It does not say but perhaps they are looking at a photograph of several people.